# Sumar documentos y montantes SQL

Tags: sql

```
 select (select m.nombre from moneda m where m.id=e.moneda_id) as moneda,e.tot_doc_che as chequesDocum, e.tot_imp_che as chequesDocumMontante,
 e.tot_doc_tra as travellDocum,e.tot_imp_tra as travellDocumMontante
 from estadisticas e
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buenas lo que me gustaría y no me sale con group by, es hacer lo que está en azul en esa imagen. Es decir tengo mi columna de chequesDocum y travellDocum, y me gustaría conseguir el total de documentos para cada moneda distinta(Moneda viene de otra tabla), y lo mismo me gustaría que para
chequesDocumMontante y travellDocumMontante se pueda hacer también la suma, como podría conseguirlo? He intentado hacerlo con group by sin el resultado esperado.
Lo de agrupar monedas es porque pueden salir varias con el mismo nombre, es decir, DOLARES CANADIENSES podría aparecer 4 veces, pero el tema sería agruparlo

**EDIT 2:**

He probado también esto:

```
 select m.nombre as moneda,e.tot_doc_che as chequesDocum
 ,e.tot_doc_tra as travellDoc,e.tot_imp_che,e.tot_imp_tra,sum(e.tot_doc_che+e.tot_doc_tra) as sumaDoc,sum(e.tot_imp_che+e.tot_imp_tra) as sumaMontante
 from estadisticas e
 left join moneda m 
 on m.id = e.moneda_id 
 group by m.nombre,e.tot_doc_che,e.tot_doc_tra,e.tot_imp_che,e.tot_imp_tra
```

Lo cual me da ésta salida:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero hay registros en la sumaMontante y sumaDoc que no se por qué no se suman bien, y tampoco me está agrupando para que no aparezcan monedas repetidas

Comment: ¿Por qué no usas [`JOIN`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentencia_JOIN_en_SQL)?

Comment: @NicolasOñate también he probado con un left join a la tabla de Moneda

Comment: Es necesario los DDL de las tablas. Explicate mejor, formula una pregunta, es igual que en tu pregunta anterior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es dificil dar una respuesta acertada sin conocer la estructura de la tablas y contar con algunos datos de ejemplo para probar. Tambien deberías especificar que motor de base de datos estás utilizando.

Basándome en las dos queries que publicaste en la pregunta, creo que esta es la query que estás buscando:

He utilizado la función `coalesce()` para que retorné cero si el valor es nulo al sumar. Quizas dicha función no esté definida en tu motor de base de datos, y deberás reemplazarla con la que corresponda.

```
SELECT m.nombre,
       SUM(e.tot_doc_che) AS chequesDocum, 
       SUM(e.tot_imp_che) AS chequesDocumMontante,
       SUM(e.tot_doc_tra) AS travellDocum,
       SUM(e.tot_imp_tra) AS travellDocumMontante,
       
       SUM(coalesce(e.tot_doc_che, 0) + coalesce(e.tot_doc_tra, 0)) AS totalDocum,
       SUM(coalesce(e.tot_imp_che, 0) + coalesce(e.tot_imp_tra, 0)) AS totalDocumMontante
       
FROM moneda m
INNER JOIN estadisticas e ON m.id = e.moneda_id 
GROUP BY m.nombre;
```

Si quieres que en la query aparezcan todas las monedas aunque no tengas estadísticas, entonces tendrías que usar `LEFT JOIN`.

Si quieres que aparezcan ceros en lugar de nulos, entonces deberías usar la función `coalesce(nombre_columna, 0)` (o la que corresponda) en todas las columnas numéricas.

Comment: Justamente era eso lo que buscaba, gracias

Comment: De nada @melolo! Estabas cerca de lograrlo con tu query. En este caso solo tenias que agrupar por m.nombre para que aparezca solo una vez cada moneda y sumar (`SUM()`) las otras columnas.